# How to add quotes to second element of a string after comma in a text file bash

Tags: bash, sed

File contents:

```
1234,/Product/number 234567
2456,/Product/number 456789
```

and so on...many lines

Want the the output as follows:

```
1234,"/Product/number 234567"
2456,"/Product/number 456789"
```

Comment: Then try to make the code yourself and post it. If there are errors someone may try to help you. No one is going to do it for you.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? Please check: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Do you want to simply display the contents of that file with the added quotes or do you want to replace those contents with the new ones (with the quotes) in that file?

Comment: Did you actually want `1234,"/Product/number 234567" 2456,"/Product/number 456789"` instead of two individual lines? In any case, my answer below will work.

Answer (score 3):

For structured data (i.e. that is describable in terms of *records* consisting of delimited *fields*) I'd suggest a tool like awk:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$2 = "\"" $2 "\""} {print}' file
```

or (more compactly - making use of the default print action)

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$2 = "\"" $2 "\""} 1' file
```

If you *really* need to do it natively in bash, then

```
while IFS=, read -r a b; do printf '%s,"%s"\n' "$a" "$b"; done < file
```

(but don't - see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)).

Answer (score 2):

###### You can do this using [perl regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) and you can substitute similar to using `sed`.

Assuming you will always have `/Product/number`  followed by a single group of digits, you can use the following command to print the changes:

```
perl -pe 's|/Product/number (\d+)|"$&"|g' filename
```

If you are satisfied with the output, you can use the following command to edit the file:

```
perl -pi -e 's|/Product/number (\d+)|"$&"|g' filename
```

- `(\d+)` matches any group of one or more digits
- `$&` backreferences the entire matched string, similar to using `&` in `sed`

Also, I use `|` as a separator instead of `/` because the string contains forward-slashes.

---

###### Alternatively, you can use `sed` by using the following command to print:

```
sed -Ee 's|/Product/number [[:digit:]]+|"&"|g' filenameme
```

or the following command to actually edit changes to the file:

```
sed -Ei 's|/Product/number [[:digit:]]+|"&"|g' filenameme
```

This command uses the extended regular expressions option `-E`

- `[[:digit:]]+` matches a group of one or more digits
- `&` backreferences the entire matched string

Answer (score 0):

If your data really are as simple as you show, all you want is to add a double quote character after the first comma and after the last character of every line. If so, just do:

```
$ sed 's/,/,"/; s/$/"/' file
1234,"/Product/number 234567"
2456,"/Product/number 456789"
```